# Left over whipped cream

Tags: baking, creme-brulee

I was just wondering if I can use leftover whipped cream to make creme brûlée? I made a big bowl of whipped cream and don’t really want to toss out the rest of it.

Comment: Welcome! Are you thinking about using it as is, in its whipped state, or what was your plan so far?

Comment: Is it whippED cream or whippING cream?

Comment: Hi Gabs, as Stephie and csk said it: you will have to tell us whether you have whipped cream or whipping cream that isn't whipped, before we can reopen and answer. Your question uses both terms.

Comment: Since it does seem more likely that the cream was already whipped, we decided to change the text instead. Please do edit it back if it was the other way round.